# JSP String formatting Truncate

Tags: java, string, jsp

Does anyone know how to truncate a string in a JSP using a tag library? I was going to use [Jakarta Taglibs](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/string-doc/index.html) but it says that it has been retired because:

> With the advent of JSTL, the core features of many of the libraries had been standardized and the need for these libraries diminished. As such, much of the Taglibs codebase moved into maintenance mode.

Comment: Do not read docs of the predecesor of JSTL. Read the real JSTL docs.  http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [JSTL substring function](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/substring.fn.html):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

${fn:substring(myVariable, 0, 5)}
```

Comment: Note that using JSTL fn:substring(), it is not necessary to check the string length. If too small, this does not give a 

StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - unlike core Java String.substring().

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the Java Scriptlets in JSP.
e.g.

```
<%
    int i = 5; // This is the number of characters to truncate

    String s = "This is a String";

    s = s.substring(0, i);
%>
```

Comment: I know you can do that but i'm more interested in using a tag library if possible.

Comment: But this is great. I don't like tags. Thanks SidCool!