# Showing part of a string via c:out

Tags: spring, maven, jstl, cout

In my application, there is a field shown on the jsp. I wrote it by using

```
<td>
<c:out value="${field}" />
</td>
```

However, I dont want everything in that value(field) to be shown. Only first 15 characters should be shown. How can I do that?
I am using spring 3.1 and it is amven project.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${fn:length(field) > 15}">
      ${fn:substring(field,0,10)}...
   </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     ${field}
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

You can use  to display your output, I have written here directly .

Comment: If you have time, I posted another question but I have not take any answer yet. The url is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764992/using-ckeditor-it-does-not-work.   Thanks for advance.

Comment: It is not necessary to check for the string length - JSTL substring() handles this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jstl substring function as described in previous answers, [JSP String formatting Truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418095/jsp-string-formatting-truncate)

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed is:

```
  ${ fn:substring( field, 0, 15 ) }
```

It is not necessary to check the string length as the JSTL fn:substring() function handles if it is passed a shorter string than the required length.

```
<c:set var="string10" value="1234567890"/>
<br/>string         : ${ string10 }
<br/>substring 0..10: ${ fn:substring( string10, 0, 10 ) }
<br/>substring 0..20: ${ fn:substring( string10, 0, 20 ) }
```

gives:

```
string         : 1234567890 
substring 0..10: 1234567890 
substring 0..20: 1234567890
```

Note that this is different behaviour to core Java String.substring(..).

```
<br/>substring 0..20: ${ string10.substring( 0, 20 ) }
```

gives a:

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```